# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

In my code, my model is compiling fine but when I am using `pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(test_labels))` to get the labels for the validation images, it gives me the following error.

```
File "train_model.py", line 43, in <module>
    pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(test_labels))])
  File "C:\Users\ariji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\ariji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)
  File "C:\Users\ariji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 497, in _process_training_inputs
    adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\ariji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 653, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What seems to be the issue? My model is a simple tensorflow sequential model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `pd.get_dummies` gives a `pd.DataFrame`. You need to convert that to `numpy.ndarray` type.

Try

```py
pd.get_dummeis(pd.Series(test_labels)).to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Somehow I got this problem when I was running an old code of mine with tf2. It used to work fine with the old tensorflow